# DateTime API only outputs DAY in the future? PHP

Tags: php, datetime

If I send a DAY and TIME (not DATE) to the [DateTime API](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) like this :

```
$tz = new \DateTimeZone("UTC");
$now = new \DateTime("now", $tz);
$then = \DateTime::createFromFormat('l g A', 'Thursday 8 PM', $tz);
```

And it is currently **Saturday 26th March**, $then, when echoed as follows :

```
echo $then->format('l jS, F');
```

Will return :

```
Thursday 31st, March
```

How do I make it return the date of the Thursday in the CURRENT week that has just passed :

```
Thursday 24th March
```

Not the next Thursday?

Comment: You could just use `strtotime('last thursday 8 pm');` and supply the time from a DateTime object to get the timezone.

Comment: @JoelHinz *last* always produces a date in the past. The OP wants the day of the current week. Today, "last Saturday" produces 2016-03-19)

Comment: Yes strtotime wasn't working out the way I needed it to for other functions not displayed here, that's why I'm using DateTime instead.

Comment: @axiac my bad, I read "that has just passed" and somehow missed the capitalised "CURRENT".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DateTime::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) uses [a lot of rules](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) to guess what you mean when you specify an incomplete or relative date. Most of the times thy guess right but some of the rules are very similar and the final result is not the one expected by the programmer.

[`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is limited, it cannot understand all the formats from the list.

You try to parse a [relative date format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php). When only the day name is specified, it is interpreted as the next occurrence of the specified day of the week (see the *dayname* entry under the *Day-based Notations* table in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).)

You can get the date you want by using *Thursday this week* instead. [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) doesn't understand relative dates that contain references to the week but [`DateTime::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) does.

Try this:

```
$then = new \DateTime('Thursday this week 8 PM', $tz);
```

Comment: Ahh I had no idea DateTime accepted similar values to strtotime. This is perfect! Thank you so much ;)

Comment: Not just similar. [`DateTime::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php), [`date_create()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) internally call the same function to parse the date strings provided to them.

Answer (score 0):

Could always call the 'sub' method on it, subtracting 7 days.

```
$tz = new \DateTimeZone("UTC");
$now = new \DateTime("now", $tz);
$then = \DateTime::createFromFormat('l g A', 'Thursday 8 PM', $tz);
$then->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'));
echo $then->format('l jS, F');
```

Comment: By always subtracting 7 days, when the day of the week specified in the date string is in the future of the current week day you get dates from the last week. For example, on the next Monday (2016-03-28) you code will return the Thursday of this week (2016-03-24), but the OP wants to get the day of the week when the code runs (which, on Monday is 2016-03-31).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't think that one through clearly enough.